# Login y registro en asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-get

estoy haciendo una web api de votaciones y al momento de crear el login y el registro se me ha dificultado ya que es la primera vez que veo esta tecnologia, les paso el codigo de mi httpGet, les agradeceria que me orientaran a hacerlo.

```
    [HttpGet("{Nombre}")]
    public ActionResult<List<Ciudadano>> GetIniciarSesion(string nombre, string primerApellido, string segundoApellido, string claveElector)
    {
        var ciudadano = _context.Ciudadanos.Where(E => E.Nombre == nombre && 
                                                E.PrimerApellido == primerApellido && 
                                                E.SegundoApellido == segundoApellido && 
                                                E.ClaveElector == claveElector).ToList();

        if (ciudadano == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return ciudadano;
    }
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que en la declaración del `Get` te faltan el resto de parámetros que recibe la función, o bien, lo que podrías hacer:

```
[HttpGet("GetIniciarSesion")]
    public ActionResult<List<Ciudadano>> GetIniciarSesion(string nombre, string primerApellido, string segundoApellido, string claveElector)
```

Luego, tu URI (para consumirla) te quedaría:

```
/GetIniciarSesion?nombre=xxx&primerApellido=xxx&segundoApellido=xxx&claveElector=xxx
```